# Physics of Ice books

Tags: resource-recommendations, ice

I am looking for some references for books on the physics of ice from a condensed matter perspective. Does anyone know any good advanced books on the subject?

Answer (score 3):

Three standard textbooks on the topic:

P. V. Hobbs, "Ice Physics", (1974) Clarendon Press, Oxford.

V. F. Petrenko and R. W. Whitworth, "Physics of Ice", (2002) Oxford.

E. R. Pounder, J. A. Jacobs and J. T. Wilson, "Physics of Ice", (2013) Elsevier.

Comment: @obe: great, it's good that it was of some help.